# How to know when to invalidate an `NSTimer`

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nstimer

Here's my issue:

I have a model class that has an `NSTimer` in it that I want the Timer to run for the entire lifespan of the model object.  Initiliazation is easy:  I just have the following line of code in the `init` method:

```
self.maintainConnectionTimer = 
             [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                              target:self 
                                            selector:@selector(maintainConnection) 
                                            userInfo:nil 
                                             repeats:YES];
```

However, my issue is, **how do I invalidate this timer when the model is released from memory?**  Now, this would usually be easy, however, as far as I know, when you schedule an `NSTimer` the OS maintains a strong pointer to the Timer object.

How should I deal with this? Is there a method that gets called right before the model is released from memory?

Comment: I've never really used this before...When I was learning Objective-C I was always told that `dealloc` is seldom used anymore.  Will my properties still be valid in the `dealloc` method?

Comment: How about dealloc? Yes, they will be. I'm typing it up as an answer.

Comment: Cool! If you post this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Check the comment's by others. You will have to strip down with a different strategy.

Comment: Whenever you are done with the object, you might have to manually invalidate the timer. As long as the timer is running, it will not be released.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...]` *retains the target*, so if the target is *self*, then your instance of the model class will never be deallocated.

As a workaround, one can use a separate object (called `TimerTarget` in the following example). `TimerTarget` has a *weak* reference to `ModelClass`, to avoid a retain cycle.

This "helper class" looks like this. Its only purpose is to forward the timer event to the "real target".

```
@interface TimerTarget : NSObject
@property(weak, nonatomic) id realTarget;
@end

@implementation TimerTarget

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    [self.realTarget performSelector:@selector(timerFired:) withObject:theTimer];
}

@end
```

Now, in your model class, you can create a timer and invalidate it in `dealloc`:

```
@interface ModelClass ()
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
@end

@implementation ModelClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        TimerTarget *timerTarget = [[TimerTarget alloc] init];
        timerTarget.realTarget = self;
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                 target:timerTarget
                                               selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                               userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.timer invalidate]; // This releases the TimerTarget as well!
    NSLog(@"ModelClass dealloc");
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    NSLog(@"Timer fired");
}

@end
```

So we have

```
modelInstance ===> timer ===> timerTarget ---> modelInstance
(===> : strong reference, ---> : weak reference)
```

Note that there is no (strong) reference from the timer to the instance of the model class anymore.

I have tested this with the following code, which creates an instance of `ModelClass` and releases it after 5 seconds:

```
__block ModelClass *modelInstance = [[ModelClass alloc] init];
int64_t delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    modelInstance = nil;
});
```

*Output:*

```
2013-01-23 23:54:11.483 timertest[16576:c07] Timer fired
2013-01-23 23:54:12.483 timertest[16576:c07] Timer fired
2013-01-23 23:54:13.483 timertest[16576:c07] Timer fired
2013-01-23 23:54:14.483 timertest[16576:c07] Timer fired
2013-01-23 23:54:15.483 timertest[16576:c07] Timer fired
2013-01-23 23:54:15.484 timertest[16576:c07] ModelClass dealloc
```

Comment: +1, Since there are no other straightforward ways to do this, I think this would be the better option in this case.

Comment: One could probably encapsulate this in a custom `AutoreleasingTimer` class.

Comment: According to the Apple docs, we 'should not attempt to subclass NSTimer'. Maybe such an AutoreleasingTimer class could have factory methods that return NSTimer objects with their targets set to an internal AutoreleasingTimerTarget class?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You are right, and subclassing NSTimer is not what I meant.

Comment: Ah right - after rereading your comment I realize that you never suggested subclassing NSTimer. My apologies.

Comment: I am wondering this is really the only way. Why doesn't Apple provide something else or are there better approaches when dealing with timing next to `NSTimer`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Martin R idea, I create custom class which easier to use, and add some checking to avoid crash.

```
@interface EATimerTarget : NSObject

// Initialize with block to avoid missing call back
- (instancetype)initWithRealTarget:(id)realTarget timerBlock:(void(^)(NSTimer *))block;

// For NSTimer @selector() parameter
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer;

@end

@interface EATimerTarget ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) id realTarget;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^timerBlock)(NSTimer *); // use 'copy' to avoid retain counting
@end

@implementation EATimerTarget

- (instancetype)initWithRealTarget:(id)realTarget timerBlock:(void (^)(NSTimer *))block {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.realTarget = realTarget;
        self.timerBlock = block;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    // Avoid memory leak, timer still run while our real target is dealloc
    if (self.realTarget) {
        self.timerBlock(timer);
    }
    else {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}

@end
```

Here is my sample class

```
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         // Using __weak for avoiding retain cycles
         __weak typeof(self) wSelf = self;
    EATimerTarget *timerTarget = [[EATimerTarget alloc] initWithRealTarget:self timerBlock: ^(NSTimer *timer) {
        [wSelf onTimerTick:timer];
    }];
         self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:timerTarget selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
         [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.timer invalidate]; // This releases the EATimerTarget as well! 
    NSLog(@"### MyClass dealloc");
}

- (void)onTimerTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
     // DO YOUR STUFF!
     NSLog(@"### TIMER TICK");
}

@end
```