# Unwind segue does not release my view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I have something like this:

My `rootViewController` is a `navigationBar` - let this be A. The rest are normal `UIViewControllers`, and are programmatically segue via push (through a button `IBAction` method).

[image: Flow diagram]

However going from D -> A, I use unwind segue (also via `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender`:).

The issue here is that when the segue is performed, B, C and D are not `deallocated`at all. Not only is this causing a memory leak issue but my timers are still running. I'm not sure why this is the case. I thought unwind segues are suppose to handle all these for you? Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `NSTimer`.

`NSTimer` retain their target. So if a view controller starts a timer with target:self, it will not be deallocated as long as the timer is running.

You can get more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490178/how-to-know-when-to-invalidate-an-nstimer/14490927#14490927.)

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

Hope this will help you...for timer invalidate on other controller