# Unwind segue (D->B) does not release C

Tags: ios, swift, memory, segue

This is a Swift 2.1 project with an iOS 8.0+ target.

Much like user Cybermew in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481736/unwind-segue-does-not-release-my-view-controllers), I have a set-up where  A->B->C->D. A is a navigation controller and the rest are regular UIViewControllers. When unwinding from D to B, C does not get released. This results in a memory leak and other unintended side-effects.

As opposed to the question linked above, I don't have any NSTimer that I know of that might keep the view in memory. What could be causing this to happen?

Code of C (trimmed):

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import AVFoundation.AVAudioSession

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var scene: GameScene!
var level: Level!

@IBOutlet weak var gameOverPanel: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var heroPicture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var villainPicture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var spellOneButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var doubleLife: UISwitch!

let attackSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Attack.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!

var backgroundMusic: AVAudioPlayer = {

    let sess = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    if sess.otherAudioPlaying {
        _ = try? sess.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, withOptions: [])
        _ = try? sess.setActive(true, withOptions: [])
    }

    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BackgroundMusic", withExtension: "mp3")
    let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!)
    player!.numberOfLoops = -1

    return player!
}()

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    level = Level(filename: "Level_0")
    scene.level = level
    scene.addTiles()
    scene.swipeHandler = handleSwipe

    skView.presentScene(scene)
    backgroundMusic.play()
    beginGame()
}
}
```

---

Moved here from chat:

`swipeHandler` is declared as:

```
var swipeHandler: ((Swap) -> ())?
```

and swap is:

```
struct Swap: CustomStringConvertible, Hashable { 

    // blabla
}
```

and once filled with a swap if calls this on the `GameViewController`:

```
func handleSwipe(swap: Swap) { 

    view.userInteractionEnabled = false 

    if level.isPossibleSwap(swap) { 
        level.performSwap(swap) 
        scene.animateSwap(swap, completion: handleMatches) 
    } else { 
        scene.animateInvalidSwap(swap) { 
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Does C contain a strong reference to B?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not.

Comment: How is C being created? Can you post the code for C?

Comment: Description updated. I cut out some parts (initialization of vars) that were taking up quite a bit of space and are most likely irrelevant.

Comment: Try commenting out parts of your code, reducing the functionality until the culprit is found. Try commenting out the code which provides and plays the background music first.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The method of elimination worked! The culprit is scene.swipeHandler = handleSwipe. This would imply that the whole GameScene class is kept alive. I'd assume that unwind would take care of that as well. Any thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102781/discussion-between-alexandros-and-vacawama).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a reference loop that is causing your viewController not to be deallocated.  I would recommend turning `swipeHandler` into a weak delegate pointer and you can call `handleSwipe` though that pointer.  That way, your GameScene will not retain any strong pointers to your GameViewController which will allow it to be freed when the unwind segue is performed.

```
protocol SwipeHandler: class {
    func handleSwipe(swap: Swap)
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController, SwipeHandler {

    var level = Level()
    var scene: GameScene!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scene = GameScene()
        scene.swipeHandler = self
    }

    func handleSwipe(swap: Swap) {
        // ...    
    }
}

class GameScene {
    weak var swipeHandler: SwipeHandler?

    // function to demonstrate call to handleSwipe
    func useSwipeHandler() {
        let swap = Swap()
        swipeHandler?.handleSwipe(swap)
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much.